# Color changes the background only for specific page from color picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a html page where there is a color picker that changes the action bar color. Here, action bar is changing only once. I wanted it to be changed in all other pages. Here's my code :

```
    <h4>Color Picker</h4>
<script>
function changeColor1(id1)
{
  document.getElementById(id1).style.color = "#00BCD4"; // forecolor
  document.getElementById(id1).style.backgroundColor = "#00BCD4"; // backcolor
}


function changeColor2(id2){

  document.getElementById(id2).style.color = "#D32F2F"; // forecolor
  document.getElementById(id2).style.backgroundColor = "#D32F2F"; // backcolor #009688
}

function changeColor3(id3){

  document.getElementById(id3).style.color = "#FFAB00"; // forecolor
  document.getElementById(id3).style.backgroundColor = "#FFAB00"; // backcolor
}

function changeColor4(id4){

  document.getElementById(id4).style.color ="#4CAF50"; // forecolor
  document.getElementById(id4).style.backgroundColor = "#4CAF50"; // backcolor
}  

</script>


<a href="#" onclick="changeColor1('myid'); return false;"><button type="button" class="btn btn-sq-xs btn-info"></button></a>

<a href="#" onclick="changeColor2('myid'); return false;"><button type="button" class="btn btn-sq-xs btn-danger"></button></a>

<a href="#" onclick="changeColor3('myid'); return false;"><button type="button" class="btn btn-sq-xs btn-warning"></button></a>

<a href="#" onclick="changeColor4('myid'); return false;"><button type="button" class="btn btn-sq-xs btn-success"></button></a>   
</div>
<a href="index.html"><h4> Logout</h4</a></p>
```

What should be done to make the color change dynamically in all other pages when clicked on a color in the existing page.

Comment: Remove your return false, and implement a real way for you to catch the id, don't pass it, it's not the best.

Answer (score 0):

Are the other pages actual different pages or dynamic (AJAX or just hidden divs coming to fore).

If you are actually navigating to other pages then your script cannot just change those pages client-side without making some call to the server. There is the option of using a cookie which stores the color scheme. Then add a script that picks up the color scheme from and sets the action-bar color according to that. This script has to work on the initiation of each of the other pages.

If they are dynamic you simply need to connect the relevant elements to the trigger event.

The code you provided is rather partial and makes it hard for me to totally analyse the situation. Hope this helps though!